# Angular httpclient returns 500 server response on CRUD

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Following the google guide for httpClient [here, Delete req](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-delete-request) and I cannot get it set up properly.
Don't think it's the backend because all CRUD requests go thorough fine on Swagger.

Trying to delete rows in a material table, this is my template markup:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <button
      mat-icon-button
      (click)="onDeleteTableRowFunc()" aria-label="Delete row">
      <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Component to the template:

```
      onDeleteTableRow() {
        const destroy = this.somedata.find(item => item.someId === this.selectedRowId);
        this.projectService.deleteProjectFunction(destroy.someId, this.projId).subscribe();
        // update user's view
        const rowIndex = this.dataSource.data.findIndex(item2 => item2.someId === this.selectedRowId);
        this.dataSource.data.splice(rowIndex, 1);
        this.dataSource.data = this.somedata;
```

and the service (note: httpOptions set correctly as var elsewhere in file):

```
  deleteProjectFunction(someId: number, prosjektId: number): Observable<{}> {

    const url = `${this.realUrl}/api/folder/${projId}/folder2/${someId}`;
    return this.httpClient.delete(url, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Updating the UI (removing the row from the table is working) and as mentioned the API is set up correctly for Swagger to work as expected.

But the above code adapted from the linked Ang6 returns a generic `project.service.ts:61 Backend returned code 500, body was: [object Object]` triggered by the pipe to catchError method.

Any idea what I am doing wrong in my delete method?

Comment: Does the network tab show errors when you call this method? Can check if the generated url is correct from there?

Comment: Looks like we were getting the wrong Id from the API because the someId was referencing an ID not in the table's data-set. So the above question code would work if the correct ID was exposed.